# Echarts : connect zoom of multiple graphs

Tags: linechart, echarts

I have four echarts in my web page. When zooming on a graph with mouse wheel,  I want the other graphs to be zoomed at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`echarts.connect`](https://echarts.apache.org/en/api.html#echarts.connect).

```js
echarts.connect([myChart1, myChart2, myChart3, myChart4])
```